# Get a descriptive reason why std::ofstream open failed

Tags: c++, file, exception, system, fstream

Is there a standard/cross-platform way to throw a descriptive exception with the reason why the file failed to be opened? (Eg: "Read-only directory", "Permission denied", "File is open in another program" etc.)

I have `SomeMethod` that receives a file from some caller and I need to write to/create that file, and in case of errors, throw an exception.

I tried using the `ofstream::exceptions` member function like so:

```cpp
void SomeMethod(std::string fileName)
{
  std::ofstream outFile;
  outFile.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::eofbit);
  outFile.open(fileName);

  // start writing to file..
}
```

But the exception thrown is not descriptive enough. I get:

> ios_base::failbit set: iostream stream error

I also tried using `std::system_error`:

```cpp
void SomeMethod(std::string fileName)
{
  std::ofstream outFile(fileName);
  if (!outFile.is_open())
  {
    throw std::system_error(
#ifdef _WIN32
      ::GetLastError(),
#else
      errno,
#endif
      std::system_category(), "Error opening " + fileName);
  }

  // start writing to file..
}
```

which gives the descriptive error I want:

> Error opening some_file.txt: Read-only file system

But, the code is a little too verbose. I was hoping for something shorter...

I created this playground: https://godbolt.org/z/b1zKKnEnz

Comment: If you have already an errno, you can use std::strerror to get a text description.

Comment: I had similar wonderings and made this post here.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269182/robust-program-to-write-an-array-of-certain-data-type-to-a-binary-file-and-read
Take a look if you want

Comment: You could simply wrap `GetLastError()`/`errno` in a helper function or macro, eg: `int getMyLastError() { #ifdef _WIN32 return ::GetLastError(); #else return errno; #endif }` or `#ifdef _WIN32 #define getMyLastError() ::GetLastError() #else #define getMyLastError() errno #endif`, and then use it in your `throw` statement: `throw std::system_error(getMyLastError(), std::system_category(), "Error opening " + fileName);`

Comment: @gerum std::strerror requires even more #ifdefs since it's deprecated by msvc (besides the #ifdef arround errno and GetLastError)

Comment: @M.Victor You have ask for a standard way to solve the problem. And both errno (C standard) and std::errno are part of thr standard.